# UITableView damping animation and layout constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, constraints, ios-animations

I'm trying to animate UITableView to act like a dropdownMenu by using its height constraint and UIView.animateWithDamping(..) block. I'm occuring weird problem with white background under tableView. 
[iPhone Simulator showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C03B0.png)

I have cleared each background color and it doesn't help much. 
Here is the code setting all subviews of dropDownView, which is a UIView:

```
required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.elements = []
    defaultSetup()
}

private func defaultSetup() {
    configureActionButton()
    configureTableView()
}
private func configureActionButton() {
    actionButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
    actionButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(actionButton)
    guard let superview                                 = actionButton.superview else {
        assert(false, "ActionButton adding to superview failed.")
        return
    }
    // Constraints
    actionButton.constrain(.Leading, .Equal, superview, .Leading, constant: 0, multiplier: 1)?.constrain(.Trailing, .Equal, superview, .Trailing, constant: 0, multiplier: 1)?.constrain(.Top, .Equal, superview, .Top, constant: 0, multiplier: 1)?.constrain(.Bottom, .Equal, superview, .Bottom, constant: 0, multiplier: 1)
    // Appearance
    actionButton.backgroundColor                        = UIColor.clearColor()
    actionButton.opaque                                 = false
    actionButton.contentHorizontalAlignment             = .Left
    actionButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    if borderVisible {
        actionButton.layer.cornerRadius                 = 5
        actionButton.layer.borderColor                  = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        actionButton.layer.borderWidth                  = 1
        actionButton.clipsToBounds                      = true
    }
    // Actions
    actionButton.addTarget(self, action: "menuAction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

private func configureTableView() {
    tableView                                           = BOTableView(frame: CGRectZero, items: elements, configuration: configuration)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.delegate                                  = self
    tableView.dataSource                                = self
    addSubview(tableView)
    guard let tableViewSuperview = tableView.superview else {
        assert(false, "TableView adding to superview failed.")
        return
    }
    // Constraints
    tableView.constrain(.Trailing, .Equal, tableViewSuperview, .Trailing, constant: 0, multiplier: 1)?.constrain(.Top, .Equal, tableViewSuperview, .Bottom, constant: 0, multiplier: 1)?.constrain(.Leading, .Equal, tableViewSuperview, .Leading, constant: 0, multiplier: 1)
    tvHeightConstraint                                  = NSLayoutConstraint(item: tableView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    tableView.addConstraint(tvHeightConstraint)

}
```

BOTableView class initializer:

```
init(frame: CGRect, items: [String], configuration: BOConfiguration) {
    super.init(frame: frame, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)

    self.items                              = items
    self.selectedIndexPath                  = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.configuration                      = configuration

    // Setup table view
    self.opaque                             = false
    self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor    = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.backgroundColor                    = UIColor.clearColor()
    self.separatorColor                     = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.scrollEnabled                      = false
    self.separatorStyle                     = .SingleLine

    self.layer.cornerRadius                 = 5
    self.layer.borderColor                  = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.layer.borderWidth                  = 1
    self.clipsToBounds                      = true
}
```

UIView animations:

```
private func showMenuWithCompletionBlock(completion: (succeeded: Bool) -> Void) {
    delegate?.menuWillShow(self)
    let tvHeight                            = frame.size.height * CGFloat(elements.count)
    tvHeightConstraint.constant             = tvHeight

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { [weak self] () -> Void in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                completion(succeeded: false)
                return
            }
            strongSelf.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                if finished {
                    completion(succeeded: true)
                }
        })
}
```

Here is the code for UIView + Constraints extension, used in code:

```
extension UIView {
/**
 :returns: true if v is in this view's super view chain
 */
public func isSuper(v : UIView) -> Bool
{
    for var s : UIView? = self; s != nil; s = s?.superview {
        if(v == s) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false
}

public func constrain(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, _ relation: NSLayoutRelation, _ otherView: UIView, _ otherAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute, constant: CGFloat = 0.0, multiplier : CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIView?
{
    let c = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: attribute, relatedBy: relation, toItem: otherView, attribute: otherAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: constant)

    if isSuper(otherView) {
        otherView.addConstraint(c)
        return self
    }
    else if(otherView.isSuper(self) || otherView == self)
    {
        self.addConstraint(c)
        return self
    }
    assert(false)
    return nil
}

public func constrain(attribute: NSLayoutAttribute, _ relation: NSLayoutRelation, constant: CGFloat, multiplier : CGFloat = 1.0) -> UIView?
{
    let c = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self, attribute: attribute, relatedBy: relation, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: multiplier, constant: constant)
    self.addConstraint(c)
    return self
}
```

}

When I tried to debug the views' hierarchy in debugger, the only view which had white background was tableView, but I have cleared the background in code. I have also tried to set tableView's backgroundView to nil as well as backgroundView.backgroundColor to clearColor(). Nothing changed.

Comment: try changing the tableView's background color to the tableViewCell's back ground color.

Comment: This also doesn't work. This background below is still white. I am afraid this view below is not actually a tableView, but something which is created for the purpose of the animation

Comment: hmm, ok once u run the application on the simulator, go back to Xcode

Select Debug>View debugging> Capture View Hierarchy, this will open in Xcode and then choose the 4th icon that looks like a cube, when it becomes grid, then you can get a 360 degree view of the simulator and see which view exactly it is that is white

Comment: I have already done that as I mentioned in question description above. The debugger says that white background belongs to tableView.

Comment: my bad, but when u set the tableview's background color to say red color, do u see red color in the place that u see  white color right now?

Comment: When I set background to red I still see white color. Probably this is not a tableView, but debugger displays it as tableView.

Comment: If you want to see the source code, I have it on my github page (~olbartek). The name of repo is BODropdownMenu, branch dropdownMenuWithConstraints. Actually this is going to be outsource in the future.

Comment: provide me with a link if you can, I have a proxy set at work that doesn't let me hit github.com

Comment: Give me some contact, email/twitter/fb whatever

Comment: shabarinath.pabba@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set the UITableView footer to a blank view, don't really know why, but it seams to help for similar issue like You have.

```
    [_tableView setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] init]];
```